# camunda deployment rest API error - multipart/form-data cannot be processed

Tags: java, maven, workflow, camunda

I am trying to deploy my BPMN to camunda using their REST API.

URL - `http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/deployment/create`  (Method POST)

Headers - `Content-Type - multipart/form-data`

The body type is form-data in postman. When I select my BPMN file and send the request I am getting this error.. why is it not working,

```
{
    "type": "RestException",
    "message": "multipart/form-data cannot be processed"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set the header separately. 
[image]